# Maintain only 3 items per row in Angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object which is similar to,

```
var object = [{ "NA" : 15, "EU" : 10, "AS" : 20, "AU" : 14, "AF" : 7}, {"NA" : 17, "EU" : 14, "AS" : 36, "AU" : 16, "AF" : 6}, {"NA" : 13, "EU" : 12, "AS" : 19, "AU":9, "AF" : 2} .....]
var fruits = ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana"...]
```

I want my table to look like this, 
[image]
Here there will be only three items per row although there are many items in the object. I want to use ng-repeat for performing the action.

I am new to Angular, and confused how to start.

Comment: The items are stored in an array of objects - so I'd say choose the three you want, and spread them into a new array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the three fields you want, store them in an array, then make a new array of `object` containing only the fields you want:

```
var want = ["NA", "EU", "AS"];
var newObject = object.map(e => {
  let obj = {};
  want.forEach(item => obj[item] = e[item]);
  return obj;
});
```

Then make your table from `fruits` and `newObject`.